# How to index file in solr using node js

Tags: node.js, solr, apache-tika

I am new to solr.

I am using node js module [Solr Client](http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/) for node js to connect with solr (solr version 4.7), Everything is working fine except file indexing.
I can't able to add file for indexing using this module. So I am going to try my custom module for file indexing. How can I do this with best way.

Comment: what do you mean by "file indexing"? do you want to index the file metadata or the file content?

Comment: both. I am using solr + tika.